# Wordpress Loop not working properly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, loops

I'm working on creating my own WP template so I'm adjusting my pure HTML + CSS to work properly with WP. However, I have some issues with creating the separate blog page, which is not the main page. This is the result I want WP loop to generate for me:

```
<div class="news-body news-body1">
<div class="article-header">Title</div>
<div class="article-body"><img src="images/article1.jpg" alt="article1" id="text-image">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit placerat diam, ac sagittis felis ornare eget.</p>
</div>
<div class="article-readmore"><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
```

So this is what my PHP code looks like in the page template:

```
<? $postCount = 0; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?if (++$postCount == 1) { ?>
            <div class="news-body news-body1">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="news-body">
        <?php } ?>
            <div class="article-header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="article-body"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            <div class="article-readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
    <p class="center"><?php _e("Sorry, but you're looking for something else"); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

From what I know, this must work just right, showing 4 posts I already have put in the admin panel. 
But it doesn't work, the code that is being generated looks like this:

```
    <div class="news-body news-body1">
                        <div class="article-header">News</div>
            <div class="article-body"></div>
            <div class="article-readmore"><a href="http://lol.ru/news">Read More</a></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

What's my problem and how do I make it work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are errors on line 1 and 4. `<?` should be `<?php`.

But there is no need to open and close php every time.

```
<?php $postCount = 0;
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if (++$postCount == 1) { ?>

<div class="news-body news-body1">

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="news-body">

<?php } ?>

    <div class="article-header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div class="article-body"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <div class="article-readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile;
else : ?>

<h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<p class="center"><?php _e("Sorry, but you're looking for something else"); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I would suggest to use a code editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to write your code. This makes it a whole lot easier to see errors.